# Move parent according to child axis in Unity?

Tags: unity, rotation, transformation, axis

Can I ask my parent to move according to the child axis? This means if I turn right, then right again, the parent has to be at 180° from its original position, and not only at 90° (because "Right" would mean : "stay on the right axis from the parent axis", and what I want is : "**move the parent according to the child axis**").

The parent has a script to move, and the child has the script to rotate, so I would need to use the new rotation from the child, and not the rotation from the parent.

My attempt so far is this one : in "MoveBody()", `oldTr = transform.position` works without a bug, but it is using the parent axis. With `oldTr = this_objW;`, there is a bug, the parent goes somewhere in the scene and move its "z" axis in an odd way :

```
this_obj = GameObject.Find("this_obj").transform;//the child to rotate
this_objW = this_obj.TransformDirection(this_obj.forward);//world

//...

MoveBody( new Vector3( 3.0f, 0, 0 ) );

//...

private void MoveBody( Vector3 vec ){

      Debug.Log("transform.position : "+transform.position+" / this_objW : "+this_objW); //same value here: Vector3(0,0,1);
      oldTr = this_objW; //transform.position;
      newTr = this_objW;//transform.position;
      newTr += vec;
      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldTr, newTr, sideSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Is it possible to do it this way? Or should I translate each axis by hand?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why not apply the rotation script to the parent? What is the intended behaviour if your parent has multiple children?